# Is there a way to get additional information from a SIGSEGV?

Tags: objective-c, crash, segmentation-fault

Below is one of our recent crash reports.  It is not symbolicated, but after symbolication, it's pointing to main.m, which doesn't make any sense.  Is there a way to get additional information out of this?  We have reviewed the other threads here as well.

The last line symbolicates to:
    17  OurApp                              0x00091d00 main (main.m:6)

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x10000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x30818fbc 0x30815000 + 16316
1   UIKit                               0x339b247d 0x33953000 + 390269
2   UIKit                               0x339b159b 0x33953000 + 386459
3   UIKit                               0x3396c6f3 0x33953000 + 104179
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3737d6af 0x37353000 + 173743
5   QuartzCore                          0x3141ae31 0x31418000 + 11825
6   QuartzCore                          0x314d49d5 0x31418000 + 772565
7   QuartzCore                          0x3141f5af 0x31418000 + 30127
8   QuartzCore                          0x3141f3c3 0x31418000 + 29635
9   QuartzCore                          0x31419a09 0x31418000 + 6665
10  CoreFoundation                      0x373d6fc3 0x37353000 + 540611
11  CoreFoundation                      0x373d4fd7 0x37353000 + 532439
12  CoreFoundation                      0x373d5331 0x37353000 + 533297
13  CoreFoundation                      0x3737703d 0x37353000 + 147517
14  CoreFoundation                      0x37376f05 0x37353000 + 147205
15  GraphicsServices                    0x30dc40d5 0x30dc0000 + 16597
16  UIKit                               0x33954991 0x33953000 + 6545
17  OurApp                              0x00091d00 0x1000 + 593152
```

Comment: What does the symbolicated stack trace look like?

Comment: OurApp - main.m and the the line number

Comment: The register states, OS version / binary UUIDs, and symbols for system libraries help in debugging a crash like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/) or another framework based on [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/). You absolutely won't find a more useful source of information w.r.t. diagnosing crashes in the field and your users will love you for it.

Comment: Ironically enough, this stack is from PLCrashReporter.  This is a great tip though!

Comment: In that case, I'm pretty useless. Good luck and hopefully someone cleverer than me answers your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

See these two other questions and my answer to them for the most likely place to start digging: [What can cause this SIGSEGV error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320955/what-can-cause-this-sigsegv-error/17184478#17184478) and [SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR Crash Reports - What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794562/sigsegv-segv-accerr-crash-reports-what-to-do/17184663#17184663). Anytime you see a stack trace like this, delegate that point back into your app at object that were already deallocated are the first place you should look. Only a code review is going to turn up problems like this.