# SIGSEGV symbolication points only to core classes

Tags: ios, crash-reports, segmentation-fault

I am using Bugsense in my app to get crash reports.
I have a repeating bug with SIGSEGV and no other details about it.

I tried to symbolicate the report but I get this:

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x33417f78 0x33414000 + 16248
1 CoreFoundation 0x36f651fb 0x36f4d000 + 98811
2 Foundation 0x32c42747 0x32b9e000 + 673607
3 CoreFoundation 0x36fdaad3 0x36f4d000 + 580307
4 CoreFoundation 0x36fda29f 0x36f4d000 + 578207
5 CoreFoundation 0x36fd9045 0x36f4d000 + 573509
6 CoreFoundation 0x36f5c4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
7 CoreFoundation 0x36f5c36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
8 GraphicsServices 0x35123439 GSEventRunModal + 136
9 UIKit 0x35205cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
10 English Club 0x00036a2b 0x34000 + 10795
```

It does not point to any of my classes (In the last line 'English Club' is the name of my app).

Does that mean that this is a bug in apple classes? how can I parse this report to get somthing helpful (like what are the +1234334 numbers in this case etc.

Thank you all
Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean that this is a bug in apple classes?

No.

> how can I parse this report to get somthing helpful

Recompile with debug symbols enabled, and run the app in the debugger. Then, if everything was done right, you'll get a symbolicated stack trace.

> what are the +1234334 numbers in this case

They're offsets from the beginning of the particular function address - and you're most likely not interested in them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this report is after symbolication

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to enable zombies and rerun in the debugger and try to reproduce the crash manually. The bug is likely somwhere in your code where you set a delegate that points to one of your objective C objects. For example, see this question which is much like yours: [SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR Crash Reports - What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794562/sigsegv-segv-accerr-crash-reports-what-to-do/17184663#17184663)