# iPhone app is crashing -- error-message sent to deallocated instance 0xa58a950

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, crash, memory-management

I n my iPhone app, I have implemented sidebar i.e. JTRevealSideBar to show the side bar on left side like facebook app
But, the problem is it was crashing after clicking on the sidebar tableview for 1st index but for other index it is perfectly working

Crash Log
    **[sidebarViewController:didSelectObject:atIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa58a950**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.sidebarDelegate) 
        {
        SALSideBarViewCell * cell = (SALSideBarViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSObject *object = cell.titleLabel.text;

        [self.sidebarDelegate sidebarViewController:self didSelectObject:object atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"sidecell";
NSString * cellText;

SALSideBarViewCell * salcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (salcell == nil) {
    salcell = [[[SALSideBarViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if ([UIHelper isPad]) {
        UIView *cellBackView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 60)] autorelease];
        cellBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"sidebar_cell_pad.png"]];
        salcell.backgroundView = cellBackView;
    } else {
        UIView *cellBackView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 40)] autorelease];
        cellBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"sidebar_cell.png"]];
        salcell.backgroundView = cellBackView;
    }
}

if ( indexPath.section == 0 ) {
    cellText = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ( indexPath.row == 0 && self.slideDecksCount > 0 )
        [salcell setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.slideDecksCount]];
    else if ( indexPath.row == 1 && [[[RDStore sharedInstance] publicUsers] count] > 0 )
        [salcell setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[[*** sharedInstance] ***] count]]];
    else if ( indexPath.row == 2 && [[[RDStore sharedInstance] premiumUsers] count] > 0 )
        [salcell setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[[*** sharedInstance] ***] count]]];
    else if ( indexPath.row == 3 && [[[RDStore sharedInstance] tagCloudlabels] count] > 0 )
        [salcell setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[[*** sharedInstance] ***] count]]];
    else if ( [dataArray count] > 4 && indexPath.row == 4 && self.jsonDecksCount > 0 )
        [salcell setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.jsonDecksCount]];
}
else {
    cellText = [services objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
salcell.titleLabel.text = cellText;
return salcell;
```

}

Please let me know where the mistake is 
Thanks

Comment: Are you using ARC or MRC? Could you please provide sidebarDelegate declaration?

Comment: Update your question with cellRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: No, I am not using ARC

Comment: Then try by retaining object, ie use below code:NSObject *object = [cell.titleLabel.text retain];And how you are declaring your delegate?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign) id<SidebarViewControllerDelegate> sidebarDelegate;

Comment: I have update my question with cellRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: The most likely cause is that you forgot to nil out your delegate refs when the Table gets deallocated: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794562/sigsegv-segv-accerr-crash-reports-what-to-do/17184663#17184663

Comment: Thanks... I fixed it..yes I didnt set delagte = self