# iPhone app is crashing: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, crash, memory-management

Please take look following method as I am getting crashed

```
 + (NSArray*) controllersByTitle:(NSString*)title andNavigationController:(UINavigationController*)navController andSideBarController:(SP2SideBarViewController *)sidebarViewController {
    if ( [title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"****", @"****")] ) {
        **** *controller;
        controller = ([[[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[**** class]]) ? ([[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]) : ([[[**** alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease]);

        controller.leftSidebarViewController  = sidebarViewController;
        sidebarViewController.sidebarDelegate = controller;
        return [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller];
    }
    else if ( [title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"****", @"****")] ) {
        **** *controller;
        controller = ([[[navController viewControllers] lastObject] isKindOfClass:[**** class]]) ? ([[navController viewControllers] lastObject]) : ([[[**** alloc] init] autorelease]);

        controller.leftSidebarViewController  = sidebarViewController;
        sidebarViewController.sidebarDelegate = controller;
        return [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller];
    }
    else if ( [title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"****", @"****")] ) {
        **** *controller;
        controller = ([[[navController viewControllers] lastObject] isKindOfClass:[**** class]]) ? ([[navController viewControllers] lastObject]) : ([[[**** alloc] init] autorelease]);

        controller.leftSidebarViewController  = sidebarViewController;
        sidebarViewController.sidebarDelegate = controller;
        return [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller];
    }
    else if ([title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"****", @"****")] || [title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"****", @"****")]) {
        UsersViewController *controller;
        controller = ([[[navController viewControllers] lastObject] isKindOfClass:[UsersViewController class]]) ? ([[navController viewControllers] lastObject]) : ([[[UsersViewController alloc] init] autorelease]);

        controller.leftSidebarViewController  = sidebarViewController;
        sidebarViewController.sidebarDelegate = controller;
        [controller setTitle:title];
        if ( [title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"****", @"****")] )
            controller.runMode = ****;
        else
            controller.runMode = ****;
        [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendView:title];

        [controller.tableView reloadData];
        return [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller];
    }
    else if ( [title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"****"], @"****")] ) {
        **** *controller;
        controller = ([[[navController viewControllers] lastObject] isKindOfClass:[**** class]]) ? ([[navController viewControllers] lastObject]) : ([[[**** alloc] init] autorelease]);

        controller.leftSidebarViewController  = sidebarViewController;
        sidebarViewController.sidebarDelegate = controller;
        return [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller];
    }
    else if ( [title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"****"], @"****")] ) {
        **** *controller;
        controller = ([[[navController viewControllers] lastObject] isKindOfClass:[**** class]]) ? ([[navController viewControllers] lastObject]) : ([[[RDATagCloudController alloc] init] autorelease]);

        controller.leftSidebarViewController  = sidebarViewController;
        sidebarViewController.sidebarDelegate = controller;
        return [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller];
    }
    else if ( [title isEqualToString:@"Crash Me"] ) {
        CFRelease(NULL);
    }
    SP2DecksViewController *controller;
    controller = ([[[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[SP2DecksViewController class]]) ? ([[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]) : ([[[SP2DecksViewController alloc] init] autorelease]);

    controller.leftSidebarViewController  = sidebarViewController;
    sidebarViewController.sidebarDelegate = controller;

    controller.runMode = ([title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"****", @"****")]) ? **** : OtherApplication;

    [controller showReloadButtonByRunMode:controller.runMode];
    [controller setTitle:title];
    //[controller.tableView reloadData];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendView:title];

    return [NSArray arrayWithObject:controller];
}
```

Console output

> -[SettingsTableViewController sidebarViewController:didSelectObject:atIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa52fd80

[Instrument Snaphot](http://screencast.com/t/NUQ0rn2n)

Comment: Why not just use Xcode's debugging capabilities ? It's much easier than trying to spot bugs by eye.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more helpful than that. Where/what line does it crash on? Anything in the console?

Comment: Did you try enabling zombies to debug better your code?

Comment: I have edited my question please look on it, i have added screen shot of the instrument(memory leak tool)

Comment: Yes i did.. please look on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152427/iphone-app-is-crashing-error-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance-0xa58a950

Comment: * -[SettingsTableViewController sidebarViewController:didSelectObject:atIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa52fd80